# Google Calendar API: Request Next Event

Tags: android, calendar

I would like to get information about when the next appointment in my Google Calendar will be, so I've read a lot of articles, most of them about how to write (Intent.ACTION_INSERT) to the Calendar and successfully did so. What I could not find is information on how to pull data from the Calendar, not even how to connect to it.

I had a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.html but it does not give an example or explanation on how to connect and/or authorize.

Using Android 4.1 and can rely upon my users using Android 4.